# How to join tables in HMVC?

Tags: codeigniter, design-patterns, database-design, hmvc

I used MVC before. Now I am a learning HMVC.
I **have product, product_category, product_description** and product_images tables in my database.
I want to display list of products in my website with basic product information. Clicking on a product will redirect to a different page and will display all the product related information.
What is the best way to achieve this according to HMVC(Modular MVC) pattern?

1. Should I create **different modules** for each table like product module, product category module etc..?(In this case I will have one model class in each **module/model**. I found this idea when searching internet)
2. Should I create **one module** called products and put all the files related to this in that module? (In this case I will be having all the product, product_category, product_description product_images model classes under **products/models**)
3. Should I follow a completely different implementation from the techniques I've mentioned above? (Please provide specific details to build this module)

(I'm using codeignitor for my development)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets simplify the things for you.

1. If you have `category` as menu (Same as magento), i will recommend you to create new module for `cateogry`
2. Coming back to product, you can manage all things with the 1 product `controller`.
3. In category, category will have its own `model` to interact with database.
4. In your product model, you can manage all kind of transactions in one model because they are part of product only.
5. If you want to move bit advance, you can have a `sql` folder in each module so that you can install the and create tables when you just drop folder to modules. For this you can create a small script where, in regular interval of time, it will check the new modules, and if that script found some new modules, it will install the `.sql` file in the `sql` folder, which will update the database schema.

Hope this will help you